# Nested loops for printing char's not working properly in switch-case in C (Unexpected behaviour)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, switch-statement, nested-loops

I made a program where I used switch case in C. In one case I used nested loops where I need to print a 2D array, but only the first line of the array got printed and rest show blank. Here is the code:

```
//sample.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 256

void createImage(int M, int N, char image[][N]){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            image[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char fileName[MAX], image[MAX][MAX], command, color;
    int M, N, X, Y, i,j;

    while(1){
        scanf("%c", &command);
        if(command == 'X') break;
        switch(command){
            case 'I':
                scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);
                createImage(M,N,image);
                break;
            case 'L':
                scanf("%d %d %c", &X, &Y, &color);
                image[Y-1][X-1] = color;
                break;
            case 'S':
                scanf("%s", fileName);
                printf("%s\n", fileName);
                for(i=0;i<M;i++){
                    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
                        printf("%c", image[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program Input:

```
I 5 6
L 2 3 A
S one.bmp
X
```

Expected Output:

```
one.bmp
000000
000000
0A0000
000000
000000
```

Actual Output:

```
one.bmp
000000
```

Compiler used is GNU GCC Compiler. I don't think if there is any mistake with the program, it might be a Compiler issue, or may be there is something which I don't know about. You can also run the program [here](https://code.hackerearth.com/b45c45a). Please someone help to let me know what the issue is!

Comment: When asking other people to read your code, please make it more legible by adding spaces. Example: `for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {`

Comment: @user3121023 : I tried it, but it isn't the issue!

Comment: @user3121023 : Yes this one worked! Thanxxx....:)